# Django model cannot call app module methods

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django app with the following structure:

```
.
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── Business
├── __init__.py
├── migrations
├── models
├── __pycache__
├── templates
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
└── views
```

In the model folder I have an `__init__.py` file which contain the following code:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from web.Business.rockynodeZabbix import Zabbix


@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_zabbix_group(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Zabbix.component("HostGroup").create(instance.id)
```

The issue it that i cannot import my app `web` module methods in the models since in several classes in the `Business` module am calling the `model` module:

```
import web.models as models
```

If I import the app module `web.Business.xxxx` in my model i get the following error:

```
File "/Users/kheshav/Linux_projects/rockynode.io/App/web/models/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from web.Business.rockynodeZabbix import Zabbix
  File "/Users/kheshav/Linux_projects/rockynode.io/App/web/Business/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .test import test
  File "/Users/kheshav/Linux_projects/rockynode.io/App/web/Business/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import web.models as models
AttributeError: module 'web' has no attribute 'models
```

How do i call my app module function in the model since i want to trigger it when a user is created.

Comment: try adding `__init__.py` to your `models` dir.

Comment: @erewok `__init__.py` already exists as i specified.

Comment: sorry. didn't read it. I see the problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have what appears to me to be a classic circular dependency problem. These are often hard to diagnose at first because you get very weird errors. Unfortunately, there's no Python traceback that says "circular dependency!"

Let's break it down.

In your `models/__init__.py` you said you have the following:

```
from web.Business.rockynodeZabbix import Zabbix
```

So, what Python does when it gets to this line, essentially, is it stops and does the following

1. Find `web.Business.__init__` and execute all top-level declarations and then add `web.Business` to imported modules.
2. Find `web.Business.rockynodeZabbix` and execute all top-level declarations and add `web.Business.rockynodeZabbix` to the imported modules and `Zabbix` to the namespace of this module.

Now, let's say you've got something like this in `web.Business.rockynodeZabbix`:

```
from web.models.some_module import some_thing
```

Well, now we have a cycle. We *already had been* importing `web.models.__init__`. As part of *that import*, we had started looking at `web.Business...`. Python has already added `web.models.__init__` to the imported modules because it's the one we started with, so in other words, for the purposes of this current import line it thinks we're done.

Later on, when you you want to use some attribute from the circular imported module, Python will often tell you it doesn't exist. This is the tell-tale sign of a circular dependency. It stopped and bailed out and never finished, so it'll often throw `AttributeError`s everywhere you want to use things from the namespace that did not get fully imported.

Here's an opinion which not everyone agrees with (have you ever used Flask, for instance?):

**Circular dependencies are an architectural problem and they must be avoided at all costs**

To solve this problem, you need to make your modules *not* import each other in this way.

For instance, think of it like a tree. You could consider `models` to be "low-level". Other things higher in the tree, then, can import `models` but `models` can't import anything except even lower-level utilities and stuff.

You would then move the code in `models` that is importing stuff from further up in the tree to another module where it belongs.

Also, nodes at the same level shouldn't know about each other.

Try to keep the tree structure in mind when situating code inside your modules:

1. No module should import anything from higher in the tree than itself.
2. No module should import anything from a unconnected node at the same level in the tree as itself (hard to enforce but extremely useful if you can organize this way).
3. Stuff at the lowest level should import **nothing** from your project. These are always going to be *safest* modules to import anywhere else.
4. Modules at the top tie together everything below them.

---

One final opinion: it's easy to create bad architectural designs in Django (not a fault of Django) because we often put tons of application logic into our `models` modules. Then, things all over the project start importing these `models` modules and then cross-importing each other. Be wary of this design pitfall.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Will try work around with the design.